# nginx with grunt-nginx - paths on Windows

Tags: nginx, gruntjs

I have nginx installed to `c:\nginx\`, and a node app at `c:\node\stock\`. I have my `gruntfile.js` at `c:\node\stock\gruntfile.js`.

I tried `config: 'c:\\nginx\\conf\\nginx.conf'` and `prefix: 'c:\\nginx'`. Also `config: '../../nginx/conf/nginx.conf'` and `prefix: '../../nginx/'`.

I'm getting this error message:

> Exception thrown in attempt to start nginx: Error: Error: not found: nginx

What should these paths be..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of `grunt-nginx` (https://github.com/alexcurtis) answered my question on github.

You have to add the `PATH` to nginx (`c:\nginx` in my case) into your Windows environment variables, then restart your console.